# How to add values to a list with no access to Add() method?

Tags: c#

I'm using ctrader's API (https://ctrader.com/api/reference/) and I would like to add all values from a 2D list (called List) into two 1D lists (called output1, output2)

```
public IndicatorDataSeries output1 { get; set; } // 1D list
public IndicatorDataSeries output2 { get; set; } // 1D list
public List<List<Thing>> List = new List<List<Thing>>(); // 2D list

public class Thing 
{
  public double value1 { get; set; }
  public double value2 { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to do it this way but I'm getting an error back saying -
**"Error CS1061: 'cAlgo.API.IndicatorDataSeries' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'cAlgo.API.IndicatorDataSeries' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

```
foreach (var list in List)
{
    foreach (var thing in list)
    {
       output1.Add(thing.value1);
       output2.Add(thing.value2);
    }
}
```

Is there another way I could add the list of values into the two outputs if it is saying there is no Add method for the IndicatorDataSeries type?

I'm also new to C# and this api so I could be missing something obvious.
Thanks

Comment: soo what's this `IndicatorDataSeries`-class _exactly_? don't you think that would be helpful to know to solve your problem?

Comment: An IndicatorDataSeries, per the documentation you provided, is an IEnumerable, not a List (two different things), and so therefore has no Add method, nor does it have any way to add elements.  Your only solution is to use something else (such as a List).

Answer (score 0):

Per second example at https://ctrader.com/api/reference/indicatordataseries , you may need to call

```
output1 = CreateDataSeries();
output2 = CreateDataSeries();
```

before the loop. Then, instead of calling `Add` method, directly manipulate using `[]` operator.

p.s. I am not familiar with cTrader. This may not be the correct way/approach.

Answer (score 0):

From docs you can see that IndicatorDataSeries created with "magic" method [CreateDataSeries](https://ctrader.com/api/reference/internals/algo/createdataseries) and later populated via index property

```
var series = CreateDataSeries();

var index = "some-index-value"
series[index] = 200 * someFactor; // dummy example
```

For your data structure `Thing` it can look like below:

```
foreach (var thing in List.SelectMany(list => list))
{
    output1[thing.value1] = thing.value2;
    output2[thing.value2] = thing.value1;
}
```